# What is the "right" way to nest components?

Tags: typescript, web-component, custom-element, lit-element, lit

This seems like a very basic questions, but neither the documentation nor code examples I found were able to tell me.

Given the following example:

```
import { FlowIdentification } from "./flow-identification";

@customElement("bb-flow")
export class Root extends LitElement {
//...
 render() {
    return html`<div>${new FlowIdentification()}</div>` 

// WORKS! Better for typisation?
```

But this also works and is probably recommended:

```
import "./flow-identification";

@customElement("bb-flow")
export class Root extends LitElement {
//...
 render() {
    return html`<div><flow-identification></flow-identification></div>`
```

But don't we lose the typings in the second approach? And does the first approach even make sense? I'm confused.

Would be cool if we could get a "How to nest components" chapter in the docs. :)

Comment: The second one is the intended way, if you have your types created properly, TS tools should be able to provide you with the autocomplete features and so on even in this case. See: https://lit.dev/docs/tools/development/#ide-plugins

Answer (score 0):

Lit elements are [custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#custom-elements). Therefore any browser API for creating HTML is a valid way to create your element and also nest it within another element. Similarly, their types (by default) work in a similar manner to native browser elements - and can optionally be improved with tooling.

Here are some ways to create elements and their typing tradeoffs. Upfront the recommended/intended way is your second example. And typing can be optionally added/enforced using a plugin such as [lit-plugin](https://lit.dev/docs/tools/development/#lit-plugin).

### Instantiating Lit elements (and any HTML elements)

#### Static html - declarative API

```html
<!-- Element in HTML context (html file, markdown, html tag function) -->
<flow-identification></flow-identification>

<!-- Nested -->
<div><flow-identification></flow-identification></div>
```

or in Lit's html tag function:

```js
const template = html`<div><flow-identification></flow-identification></div>`;
```

In this case, types can be added via additional tooling like the lit-plugin. See: https://lit.dev/docs/tools/development/#lit-plugin

#### With imperative DOM APIs

```js
// `el` will be typed correctly in TypeScript if found on HTMLElementTagNameMap
const el = document.createElement('flow-identification');
document.body.append(el); // Example of nesting in `body` element.
```

Note that your `FlowIdentification` element will be typed in the example above if the following was added to your TypeScript source code [[documentation link]](https://lit.dev/docs/components/defining/#typescript-typings):

```
declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    "flow-identification": FlowIdentification;
  }
}
```

`innerHTML` also works although won't be typed:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "<div><flow-identification></flow-identification></div>";
```

And as you mentioned, it is also possible to construct a custom element via its constructor [[reference]](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#custom-elements-autonomous-example), but it must already be defined in the custom elements registry.

```js
const el = new FlowIdentification();
```